# How to convert a string to UTF-16 format in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a google app script which converts a string to UTF-16 unicode format. For example 
`Input:Hello World
 Output:\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f \u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064`

I actually want the script to convert the column containing Arabic words in the goggle doc spreadsheet to UTF-16 format. Like-

```
Input: مرحبا بالعالم
Output: \u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0644\u0645
```

Is there any way I could do this in Google app script ? If yes, please point me to the right direction on ways to doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO is not the place to have a complete script written for you from scratch but a formula might help you get started:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,,ArrayFormula(lower("\u0"&DEC2HEX(CODE(SPLIT(regexreplace(A1,"(\D)","$1\"),"\"))))))
```

The above though recognises a space.

[REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) here 'captures' (the `(   )`) each individual non digit character (the [class](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) `\D`) in `A1` and appends to each element of the captured group (`$1`) a backslash. [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) parses the result of REGEXREPLACE at each `\`. [CODE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094122) converts the characters into decimal map values which [DEC2HEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093137) then converts to signed hexadecimal format for appending to `\u0` with the concatenation operator `&`. [LOWER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094083) converts the alphabetic elements returned by DEC2HEX as capitals into lower case. SPLIT created an array so [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) is required for the functions to process all the individual elements (eg DEC2HEX is a non-array function). [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) then stitches all the pieces together and is used with defaults for the first two parameters.

Comment: Thank you @pnuts. Yes this should help. But, could you please explain me what this formula does? I'm actually very new to writing scripts.

Comment: but how it is used in script editor gs file